# How to make Intellisense in Visual Studio 2012 not to substitute text right to the cursor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

While programming I often realize that I need to add something before already typed code. For example I type the name of the variable:

```
input[0]
```

and then I realize that my array is of type string and I need to convert it. So, I move to the beginning of the word (with Ctrl-Left Arrow) and start typing

```
Convert.To|input[0]
```

with pipe used to show the position of my cursor. I get some suggestions from Intellisense, including the ToInt32() method I am looking for. But as long as I confirm this suggestion with Tab or Space, I get the following:

```
Convert.ToInt32(|)[0]
```

So, the text from the cursor position to the end of the word is substituted with suggestion, and this is definitely not what I want.

This problem is not specific for VS 2012 and might be due to some extensions I have installed, but my attempt to pursue its origin did not yield anything. I have following extensions installed: ReSharper, PowerCommands, Productivity Power Tools.

Comment: Type a space to avoid this.

Comment: @HansPassant: This solution I know, but it looks somewhat clumsy to me. See my comments to 280Z28's reply for some clarifications why I don't like it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are entering an unrelated expression before an identifier, add a space before you start typing the new expression. This will prevent the completion from replacing the existing identifier.

For example, if `|` marks the caret, the following scenario would avoid the problem you are facing.

```
Convert.To| input
```

This code completion feature is designed to prevent the insertion of incorrect identifiers. If Visual Studio behaved like some other IDEs I know of, using the code completion feature in your original example would result in the insertion of `ToInt32input`, which would never be valid.

If you are interested in additional thoughts regarding this feature in general, I have described this as the *Extend* (default for Visual Studio) and *No-extend* (default for NetBeans, Eclipse, and others) modes in my blog article [Code Completion filtering, selection, and replacement algorithms](http://blog.280z28.org/archives/2011/12/105/).

Comment: I see your point, but this increases the number of keystrokes from two (Ctrl- <- + Ctrl-Space) to 5 (Ctrl- <-, (space), <-, Ctrl-Space) for the same action. Is there a way to insert space to the right of the caret, without moving it?

Answer (score 0):

A two years later answer. But it might still be useful for some.

What helped for me in VS2015 (which might also work in VS2012) is to add the a space character to the list of 'Member List Commit Characters' in the Intellisense settings.

After this the characters after the cursor are not removed by an auto-completion.